# clearInterval() and setInterval() when all animations are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is repeatedly being called with setInterval creating animations. If there are still animations running I need it to stop calling the function until all the animations are complete. The code I am using is as follows:

EDIT: Added coded where I am removing the animated elements from the DOM, is that the problem?

```
var serviceLoop = setInterval(serviceQueue, LOOP_POLL_MS); //10 ms

function serviceQueue()
{
       //do some animations..
       function moveMan(from, to, plane)
      {
        (function() {

            var tmp_from = from;
            var tmp_to = to;
            var tmp_plane = plane;
            var pos = tmp_from.offset();
            var temp = tmp_from.clone(true);

            temp.css({ "visibility":"visible",
                "position":"absolute",
                "top":pos.top + "px",
                "left":pos.left + "px"});
           temp.appendTo("body");
           tmp_from.css("visibility", "hidden");
        //if (!tmp_plane) tmp_to.css("visibility", "hidden");
           temp.animate(to.offset(), moveMan.ANIMATION_TIME, function() {
                tmp_to.css("visibility", "visible");
                temp.remove();
           });
       })();
     }
       if ($(":animated").length > 0)
        {
            clearInterval(serviceLoop);
            $(":animated").promise().done(function() {
                serviceLoop = setInterval(serviceQueue, LOOP_POLL_MS);
            });
        }
}
```

The problem I am having is after a couple of animations the function passed to done() is never called, and the script stops.

Comment: Why in the world are you polling every 10ms for animations to be done when it gives you a notification when its done.  Unless there's more to this function, what you have above makes no sense to me.

Comment: There's a lot more to it, it needs to keep polling even with no animations running. I thought about chaining the animations together but it didn't work out. I need to know why the above doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is the rest of your code ever removing any of the DOM objects involved in these animations?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am, that must be the problem. Let me post the code where it's removing.

Comment: You're doing it wrong, there's no excuse in the world for that code, you can use promises, callbacks or whatever to notify you when the animations start and stop and just about anything really, instead you're polling 100 times each second to see if something is animating, which is as horrible as it gets.

Comment: @adeneo I am also polling to see if objects in a priority queue (based on time) have to be removed. The animations aren't really based on when another animation completes. I just need to prevent them from overlapping and pause the polling if they are.

Comment: Either way, you're still doing it wrong. You're clearly using `if ($(":animated").length > 0)` which means you're looking for elements that are currently animating 100 times every single second (not really, as most browser has a 60-70ms minimum) instead of just having the animations *tell you when they are done*.

Comment: @adeneo - actually, he's not polling for the animation to complete.  Because as soon as there is an animation running, he stops the interval and waits for it to tell him when it's done.  I'm still not a fan of the way the code is written, but it's not actually doing it as badly as you said.

Comment: @adeneo I'm sure you're right and there's a better way to do it, it was my very first JS experiment. I'm still not understanding why removing the element from the DOM causes it to not work though.

Comment: As @jfriend00 says, if you remove the element, the promise attached to the animation of that element never resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that you end up waiting on a `promise()` that is waiting on some animations, but then you remove some of those objects from the DOM and then their animation never finishes so the promise never resolves.

See this quote from the jQuery doc for `.promise()`:

> Note: The returned Promise is linked to a Deferred object stored on
>   the .data() for an element. Since the.remove() method removes the
>   element's data as well as the element itself, it will prevent any of
>   the element's unresolved Promises from resolving. If it is necessary
>   to remove an element from the DOM before its Promise is resolved, use
>   .detach() instead and follow with .removeData() after resolution.

One quick hack might be top call `.stop(true)` on any item that you are removing from the DOM.

In general, this code needs to be rewritten to be safe from that possibility and hopefully to rethink how you approach whatever it is you're trying to do every 10ms because that's generally a bad design.  You should use events to trigger changes, not a 10ms polling operation.  You have not explained the purpose of this code so it's not clear to me what alternative to suggest.

Comment: temp.stop(true) before temp.remove() does indeed fix it. I'm not sure exactly why though. If the complete function is called, Promise Object not resolved, done is not called already?

Comment: @svenoaks - see the quote from the jQuery docs I added to my answer.  The docs explicit tell you that you will create this problem if you use `.remove()` before the promise is resolved.  In your case, `.stop()` is probably better and easier than what the `.promise()` doc recommends as a work-around.